# Rails 3 ActiveModel Nested Class I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, nested-class, activemodel

Given the following class definition in ruby:

```
class Conversation
  class Message
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    attr_accessor :quantity
    validates :quantity, :presence => true
  end
end
```

How can you use i18n to customize to error message.
For example the correct lookup for the class Conversation would be

```
activemodel:
  errors:
    models:
      conversation:
        attributes:
          quantity:
            blank: "Some custom message"
```

But what is it for the Message class?
I tried:

```
activemodel:
  errors:
    models:
      conversation:
        message:
          attributes:
            quantity:
              blank: "Some custom message"

activemodel:
  errors:
    models:
      message:
        attributes:
          quantity:
            blank: "Some custom message"

activemodel:
  errors:
    models:
      conversation::message:
        attributes:
          quantity:
            blank: "Some custom message"
```

None of them work
Any ideas or is this a bug with ActiveModel or I18n?

Answer (score 4):

Use a / for namespaces

```
activemodel:
  errors:
    models:
      conversation/message:
        attributes:
          quantity:
            blank: "Some custom message"
```